# Return maximum datetime value

Tags: python, datetime, series

This is my code

```
file = pd.read_excel(open("file name",'rb'),sheetname="data")
max_vol = file["Voltage"].max()
max_time = file.loc["Voltage"]==max_vol,"Timestamp"]
```

My Timestamp has data like this

```
0      2018-03-01 00:00:00
1      2018-03-01 00:05:00
2      2018-03-01 00:10:00
3      2018-03-01 00:15:00
4      2018-03-01 00:20:00
5      2018-03-01 00:25:00
6      2018-03-01 00:30:00
7      2018-03-01 00:35:00
8      2018-03-01 00:40:00
9      2018-03-01 00:45:00
10     2018-03-01 00:50:00
11     2018-03-01 00:55:00
12     2018-03-01 01:00:00
13     2018-03-01 01:05:00
14     2018-03-01 01:10:00
15     2018-03-01 01:15:00
16     2018-03-01 01:20:00
```

When printing max_time, i am getting a result like

```
624   2018-03-03 04:00:00

Name: Timestamp, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

but i want only

```
2018-03-03 04:00:00
```

can someone help me in this regard

Comment: Getting a result like?

Comment: You haven't shown us your result...

Comment: sorry by mistake i have pressed enter, its updated now

Comment: Double quotes in ```max_time = file.loc["Voltage]==max_vol,"Timestamp"]
``` is not proper

Comment: Does file.at[file["Voltage"] == max_vol,"Timestamp"] work for you?  is not working  getting following error At based indexing on an integer index can only have integer indexers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `argmax` to extract the index of the largest element, and then use `pd.DataFrame.loc`:

```
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'])  # convert to datetime
res = df['datetime'].loc[df['voltage'].argmax()]
```

If you know your index is an integer range beginning 0, e.g. `[0, 1, 2]`, then you can equivalently use the more efficient `.iat` or `.iloc` accessors.

[`pd.Series.argmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19.2/generated/pandas.Series.argmax.html) returns the Index of first occurrence of maximum of values. [`pd.DataFrame.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) permits indexing by index label, so linking the two we reach the desired result.

Comment: Thanks, but I want the time when voltage is maximum,,,,, if i am not wrong your code will providing when the time is largest.

Comment: Thanks it worked .... but can you explain or give some link for the difference between  df['datetime'].loc[df['voltage'].argmax()] and max_time=df.loc[df['voltage']==max_demand,"datetime'"] where max_demand=df['voltage'].max()... or if possible share some link